# How to suppress warnings from internal Visual Studio files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-warnings

I set the warning level to EnableAllWarnings (/Wall) in Visual Studio 2012 and in this simple program:

```
#include "math.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I got several warnings like:

> `1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\math.h(161): warning C4514: 'hypot' : unreferenced inline function has been removed`

If I replace the `"math.h"` to `"string.h"` I continue receiving warnings about the `string.h` and so on.

Does anyone know how to remove these warnings?

Comment: How did you include out of the same directory `math.h`? Is your code in the Visual Studio Include directory?

Comment: vote for https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/14717934-add-a-cl-exe-option-for-system-headers-like-gcc-s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will do the trick:

```
// you can replace 3 with even lower warning level if needed 
#pragma warning(push, 3) 

#include <Windows.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include "math.h"
//include all the headers who's warnings you do not want to see here

#pragma warning(pop)
```

If you plan to port your code to a non MS environment then you may wish to wrap all used external headers in a specific header so that it can be changed when porting.

Comment: [The almighty Google has an answer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op)

Comment: This is a good solution, and one I use quite frequently. Definitely good to be aware of if you like to compile with "All Warnings" enabled. But it doesn't fix this specific problem because warning C4514 isn't raised until the end of the compilation unit is reached.

Answer (score 8):

Look carefully at the warning messages you're actually getting:

```
1> warning C4514: 'hypot' : unreferenced inline function has been removed
```

If you are saying to yourself *"so?!"*, then that's exactly my point.

[Warning C4514](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cw9x3tcf.aspx) is a notoriously *useless* one and is literally just crying out to be suppressed globally. It is a completely non-actionable item and describes an expected case when you're working with a library.

[Warning C4711](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k402bt7y.aspx)—a function has been selected for inline expansion—is another noisy warning you'll see. Of course, you'll only get this one when compiling with optimizations enabled, which is probably why you haven't seen it yet.

Like the linked documentation says, these are "informational warnings" and they're disabled by default. Which is great, except that I, like you, prefer to compile my code with "All Warnings" (`/Wall`) enabled, and these just add noise. So I turn them back off individually.

You can disable these warnings either by adding the suppressions to your project's properties in the VS IDE, or you can use pragma directives at the top of your code file (e.g., in your precompiled header):

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable: 4514 4711)
```